# Google Apps Marketplace scope mapping between v1 and v2

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We're about to begin the process of migrating customer domains from GAM v1 to GAM v2.  We've done a trial migration, but have found that the domain needs to grant access to the new app via the Settings tab of the new app.  The migration is supposed to be seamless (i.e. domains shouldn't have to grant access to the new app) if the scopes match up.  We're wondering where we have a mismatch.

Below are the GAM v1 scopes and the GAM v2 scopes.  Can anyone tell us definitively which GAM v2 scope is causing the issue?

GAM v1 app scopes

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/
https://docs.google.com/feeds/
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly
https://mail.google.com/
https://sites.google.com/feeds/
```

GAM v2 app scopes

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
https://sites.google.com/feeds/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles
https://docs.google.com/feeds/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2 scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit.readonly" seems to be added, as there is no "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/policies/#readonly" scope in your OAuth1 list. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2#scope_equivalencymapping) for more info on scope mapping.

Comment: That, and https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles appears to be new in the v2 list.